# Any way to detect the procedure status of a CSS3 transition/transform/animation?

Tags: html, css, transition

Let's say, if there is a CSS3 transition/transform/animation assigned to an DOM element, is there anyway that I can detect the status of the procedure?

The reason I wanna do this is because I'm looking for something like transition chaining, e.g., running one transition after the previous one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done something similar in http://cssglue.com/cubic, it's a transition that adds or removes a class at the end of the transition.

Here is how you would chain a transition:

```
element.addEventListener(webkitTransitionEnd, function(ev){
            if(ev.propertyName == "min-width") { //listen to property you're changing
        element.className += " classWithNewTransition";
            }
}, false);
```

Comment: Ah, never realized that there is a event set working for webkitTransition*. Thank you very much! That's all I need. :D